# Reserved space is very less than data space for a table in SQL Server. If the database records will keep on inserted, is this will cause any issue?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-administration

Reserved space is very less than data space for a table in SQL Server.

- Is this will cause any issue?
- Is auto increment is possible for reserved space?

Please find the table details:

```
rows         4020
reserved    2974576 KB
data        2974168 KB
index_size       40 KB
unused          368 KB
```

Kindly advise on this.

Comment: It is not necessary to manually make space for tables. That happens automatically. The only time you'll have space issues is if you have an upper limit on your data file or if you run out of disk space.

Comment: `EXEC YourDatabase..sp_spaceused`. The unused space is available to table expansion (in 64K extent increments). Once the unused space is exhausted, the data file(s) will grow (if autogrow is enabled) or new data files must be added.